# sustituir un valor numérico del DOM por uno nuevo con javascript

Tags: javascript

La pregunta es muy simple. Recojo un valor de la siguiente manera:

```
const costeEstimado = document.querySelector('#costeEstimado').innerHTML;
```

Esto me devuelve el valor correspondiente. Ahora lo que necesito, es sustituir ese valor por otro.

He intentado:

```
costeEstimado.setAttribute('value', 5);
```

En este caso de ejemplo quiero sustituirlo por 5, pero me dice que setAttribute no es una función.

¿Cúal es la función o sintaxis correcta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola deberias cojer el objeto *#costeEstimado* y no solo su atributo *innerText* para porder trabajar con todos los atributos del objeto, te recomiendo lo siguiente:

```
let costeEstimadoObj = document.querySelector('#costeEstimado');
const costeEstimado=costeEstimadoObj.innerHTML;
```

para substituir el valor solo tienes que hacer:

```
costeEstimadoObj.innerHTML=5;
```

Comment: Perfecto!!! Funciona!!! Muchas gracias!!